# JAVA- Adding Host name verifier to a soap client generated with wsimport (fixing Common Name mismatch in ssl certificate error)

Tags: java, ssl, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I am getting the following exception while calling a soap web service;

**The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.**

This is because the soap endpoint URL has an IP address instead of the domain name in the SSL certificate. In my other java applications, I usually fix this using this code;

```
 HostnameVerifier {
@Override
public boolean verify(String hostName,
    SSLSession session) {
  return hostName.equals("serverIP");
}
```

But for this case, I created the client using **WSIMPORT** tool in Netbeans, and I can't figure out how to inject the hostname verifier code. I have tried using the sun internal API (though not recommended) like; `((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier, new HostNameVerifierClass());`
 but this did not work either.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't you just regenerate (reconsume) the web service WSDL using the hostname instead of the IP address so everything matches.

Comment: I am integrating with an external system, and they provided a hostname on test which I used to generate WSDL and saved it locally. But on production, they have provided an endpoint with an IP and they said they can't provide URL with a hostname.

Comment: Thats really a arse backwards way of doing things IMHO. So the production URL should use an IP address and the "test" environment uses a hostname?  If thats the case I'd add three env-entry's to your web.xml.  One entry would be a boolean "isTest", then next two would be strings.  First string would be WSDL URL for test env, second would be WSDL URL for production.  In your code, you inject those three resources. The logic in code would then be if isTest is true, use the test URL, if false, use the prod URL.  Then in the generated SOAP stubs, you would remove the hardcoded URL.

Comment: And replace it with a variable that would be set by the other code that determines the environment.  I do this with all my projects as I have to deploy to QA, UAT and production, all have different URL's.  This would likely solve your hostname/IP address issue, you just have to change isTest to true or false when deploying to the respective environment.  If you need some example code - I could whip something up for you.

Comment: @JGlass how would that solve the hostname issue? When isTest=false, the endpoint URL will be the production one with IP. 

To solve this, I decided to re-do the application using a different method that gives me more control, instead of wsimport. This worked fine for me.

Comment: I thought the host name and IP address were causing a conflict between test and production as compared to what you have in your keystore so I thought you could dynamically change the endpoint between environments - of course you'd need both entries in your keystore as trusted.  I'm glad you got it working either way!  You might "answer" your own question with some sample code on how you got it working to build up your reputation!